# Implement Interface at run-time PHP

Tags: php, cartalyst-sentinel

Hi Im working on a login application using slim and cartalyst\sentinel. When i create new instance of sentinel reminder  `$reminder =  new Cartalyst\Sentinel\Reminders\IlluminateReminderRepository;` it give an error to implement UserRepositoryInterface `error __construct() must implement interface Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\UserRepositoryInterface`.

**My Question is how can i implement an interface on run-time in php.**

Whereas at above i used activation class which also implement an interface in src code like `class IlluminateActivationRepository implements ActivationRepositoryInterface` but it do not give error.

This below activation class is working fine.

```
$activation = (new Cartalyst\Sentinel\Activations\IlluminateActivationRepository)->create($user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i solved by this supplying user repository object.

```
$users = $app->container->sentinel->getUserRepository();

 $reminder =  new Cartalyst\Sentinel\Reminders\IlluminateReminderRepository ( $users );
```